# Migrating from SVN to TFS (what to do about externals)

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tfs

So we are trying out TFS right, for the most part you can pretty much figure it out, we created a test project and added it etc. All went well. The thing I haven't really grokked is what to do about externals, we have two large projects and they both reference a shared core project, and then some of the other parts of those two solutions are separate projects themselves which of course are externals as well.

We don't care about the history (we are at a point where we can make a clean break) so I was planning to go the route of 1) create new TFS 2) add projects exported from SVN.

Again my question is how to handle the externals - If someone coule point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no built-in support for externals in TFS. I haven't found any 3rd party tools to help either. You probably need to set up a build system for those external projects, and deploy binaries to your developers. There are systems for doing these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Subversion, TFS branches exist in "path space." So, you could check in your "externals" and create a branch for each distinct version of them you want to reference. Then, you can configure your workspace to reference the appropriate version from the corresponding branch path. Alternatively, you could consider managing these components via NuGet, setting up a private NuGet feed (can be as simple as a UNC path).